# FluentNHibernate one-to-one Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I have 3 tables:

Table: **Company**, Columns: Id, Name

---

Table: **User**, Columns: Id, Name, CompanyId

---

Table: **CompanyOwnerInfo**, Column: Id, CompanyId, OwnerName.....

---

CompanyId column in both **User** and **CompanyOwnerInfo** tables are mapping to **Company.Id**

My question is how to create a One-to-One mapping for **User** and **CompanyOwnerInfo** table without **Company** table involved? because when I use **User** object to getting **CompanyOwnerInfo** there is no necessary to join the **Company** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public UserMap()
{

    References(x => x.Company, "CompanyId");

    References(x => x.CompanyOwnerInfo, "CompanyId")
        .PropertyRef(compOwner => compOwner.Company)
        .Fetch.Join()
        .Not.LazyLoad()   // if needed
        .ReadOnly();      // important otherwise you have Exception on save because both References want to write to the same column
}
```